# Frame a UIView with transparent region

Tags: uiview, swift3

I have put a normal UIView in IB in my UIViewController, and set the view to a UIView subclass with the following draw method:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    self.isOpaque = false
    self.backgroundColor?.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let insetRect = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 4)
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    UIRectFill(insetRect)
}
```

The expected result should be that the background color (white) is shown as  a line on top and bottom of the view. That indeed is what happens. But I would like the inset rectangle to be transparent, that is why I set the color to clear. But the result is black instead. See the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing it, subclassing UIView, and this time I get the expected transparency in the middle:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    let top = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: 4))
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    top.fill()
    let bottom = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height - 4, width: self.bounds.width, height: 4))
    bottom.fill()
}
```